# Validation works incorrectly for React-select with Formik on mobile device

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-select, yup

I have connected React-select element with Formik. Validation works fine in a desktop browser. But in mobile browser or mobile browser emulator, I am getting a validation error on first React-select element value change. But I am not getting error on the next value changes. Is this bug in Formik or React-select? Is it possible to fix this issue?

Here is example on codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-mcnulty-62euu?file=/index.js

Please check it only in mobile browser or mobile browser emulator since validation works fine in a desktop browser.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue recently using `react-select` with `formik`, only occurring on mobile browsers/emulators.

The issue appears to be due to react-select causing an onBlur when a selection is made. This onBlur was causing validation of the field immediately after setting the field values, resulting in this known issue occurring: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/2457

The best solution I found is to set your react-select component to not blur when a selection is made:

```
<Select
  ...
  blurInputOnSelect={false}
/>
```

Another slightly more hacky fix in some cases would be to add a small delay to places where you blur/set touched

```
setTimeout(() => {
  formik.setFieldTouched(name, true)
}, 100)
```

The suggestion by Anveshiano Manney would also work in cases where you don't need `validateOnBlur` for the entire form

Comment: This solution `blurInputOnSelect` works for me. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, not entirely sure why it's not working properly in the mobile browser(safari). However it can be fixed by preventing the validation  on "onBlur".

```
  <Formik
      validateOnBlur={false}
      ....
   >
```